# Http post forwarding on tomcat level to different domain

Tags: http-post, tomcat7, forwarding

I have two set of server on different domains using tomcat .

Now I want to forward http post call from one server to another preserving the payload in http entity throughout.

Problem is I donot want to change code and want this to be done on tomcat level anymeans.

I currently is trying to use URLrewriteFilter but not getting through.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

URLrewriteFilter may help. You can define a proxy type for  element.

> The request will be proxied to the full url specified. commons-http
>   and commons-codec must both be in the classpath to use this feature.

Sample:

```
<rule>
    <name>A Rule</name>
    <from>^/something$</from>
    <to type="proxy">http://anotherserver.com/something</to>
</rule>
```